# Bibliotecas de ícones

Tags: html, css, font

Gostaría de saber de vocês, quais são as bibliotecas de ícones que vocês utilizam, de preferência gratuitas, eu por exemplo, comecei a usar a Font-Awesome, porém ela não atendeu algumas de minhas necessidades.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Murilo, atualmente costumo usar ícones em SVG por questão de performance, por ser estilizável e animável com CSS.

**Segue uma lista abaixo para sites onde pode achar ícones em SVG:**

- [Flaticon](http://www.flaticon.com/)
- [Leungwensen](http://leungwensen.github.io/svg-icon/)
- [SvgPorn](http://svgporn.com/) (Não é besteira não, juro :D)
- [SvgCuts](http://svgcuts.com/blog/category/fsvgotw/)
- [Vecteezy](https://www.vecteezy.com/)

A maioria dos citados acima são free e alguns são free com alguns conteúdos pagos.

Como sua pergunta foi bem superficial e eu que estou evangelizando o SVG por aqui, vou te recomendar um repositório **MUITO** bom do Willian Justen sobre SVG, o [Awesome SVG](https://github.com/willianjusten/awesome-svg/) para caso queira saber mais.

Answer (score 1):

Podes experimentar estes http://materializecss.com/icons.html embora os da fontawesome, ao meu ver, são os mais bacanos

Comment: muito bom man, valeu :3